# Problems with global boolean in jquery

Tags: jquery, boolean

I've a problem that I don't understand. correctLogin is a boolean to control the correct/incorrect login. The initial value is false, and recoverUser return a value. If this value not empty correctLogin is true.

But correctLogin doesn't change. It is always false.

The commented alert show me true if it is correct, but in recordLogin correctLogin is false again.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginButton").click(function(){
    var correctLogin = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recoverUser.php",
        data: "nameUser="+$("#nameUser").val()+"&passwordUser="+$("#passwordUser").val(),
        success: function(groupUser){
            if(groupUser=="") {
                $("#add_err").html("Incorrect Data");
            } else {
                $("#add_err").html("Correct Data...")               
                sessionStorage.setItem('sesionGrupo',groupUser);
                sessionStorage.setItem('sessionUser',$("#nameUser").val());
                sessionStorage.setItem('sessionPassword',$("#passwordUser").val());
                correcLogin = true;
                // alert(correctLogin);
            }
        },
    }); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recordLogin.php",
        data: "nameUser="+$("#nameUser").val()+"&statusLogin="+correctLogin,
        success: function(){
        },          
    });         
});
```

Comment: put your second code in side first ajax success function . this will not work due to javascript asynchronous  nature .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ajax is asynchronous,it will not wait for the success event to happen. So the value of that variable will be default value when you go for the next request.

Change the code like, move the second ajax call to success event of the first one.

```
$("#loginButton").click(function() {
    var correctLogin = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recoverUser.php",
        data: "nameUser=" + $("#nameUser").val() + "&passwordUser=" + $("#passwordUser").val(),
        success: function(groupUser) {
            if (groupUser == "") {
                $("#add_err").html("Incorrect Data");
            } else {
                $("#add_err").html("Correct Data...")
                sessionStorage.setItem('sesionGrupo', groupUser);
                sessionStorage.setItem('sessionUser', $("#nameUser").val());
                sessionStorage.setItem('sessionPassword', $("#passwordUser").val());
                correcLogin = true;
                // alert(correctLogin);
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "recordLogin.php",
                data: "nameUser=" + $("#nameUser").val() + "&statusLogin=" + correctLogin,
                success: function() {},
            });
        },
    });

});
```

Comment: why down vote here? downvoter please care to comment.

Answer (score 1):

It works! Thanks! It is a useful information. Link jquery ajax help me in future functions.